# How to count number of times a specific result/output is seen in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a script of getting of A-records of all IP-s from my network.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    host_starting=test
    dns=test.com

    for hosts in "${host_starting}"{1..200}."$dns"; do
    addr=`dig +short $hosts`
    echo "$addr=$hosts"
    done
```

I have output:

```
192.168.1.1=test1.test.com
192.168.1.2=test2.test.com
192.168.1.3=test3.test.com
192.168.1.4=test4.test.com
192.168.1.5=test5.test.com
192.168.1.6=test6.test.com
192.168.1.7=test7.test.com
192.168.1.8=test8.test.com
192.168.1.9=test9.test.com
192.168.1.10=test10.test.com
10.1.1.1=test11.test.com
10.1.1.1=test12.test.com
...
...
...
a lot of 10.1.1.1
```

I don't want to show "10.1.1.1".
I can resolve it:

```
if [ $addr != "10.1.1.1" ]; then
```

But, how can i calculate addresses and make condition:
if count of "10.1.1.1" repeats more than 2, we should not show it address.

Comment: Which version of bash? Can we assume 4.0 or newer?

Comment: 4.4.11 version of bash

Comment: Good -- my answer should be fine then.

Comment: Looks like a job for `awk` to me... any reason not to tag with `awk`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, ...*grumble* about tagging with every reasonable tool -- that's how we get questions tagged `sed` `awk` `sh` `bash` `perl` `python` `ksh` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you only want this behavior for specific IPs

```
#!/bin/bash

# Only IP addresses preinitialized in this associative array are tracked
declare -A seen=( [10.1.1.1]=0 )

host_prefix=test
dns=test.com

for host in "$host_prefix"{1..200}."$dns"; do
  addr=$(dig +short "$host")
  [[ ${seen[$addr]} ]] && {
    (( seen[$addr] += 1 ))
    (( seen[$addr] > 1 )) && continue
  }
  printf '%s\n' "$addr=$host"
done

# Just for the fun of it, let's dump our counters to stderr...
declare -p seen >&2
```

#### If you want this behavior for *every* IP

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A seen=( )

host_prefix=test
dns=test.com

for host in "$host_prefix"{1..200}."$dns"; do
  addr=$(dig +short "$host")
  (( seen[$addr] += 1 ))
  (( ${seen[$addr]} > 1 )) && continue
  printf '%s\n' "$addr=$host"
done

# Just for the fun of it, let's dump our counters to stderr...
declare -p seen >&2
```

#### General Notes

`declare -A seen` defines an array where the indexes are strings, not integers.

`(( seen[$addr] += 1 ))` increments the counter associated with the address in `$addr` by one; an empty key is evaluated as 0.

`[[ ${seen[$addr]} ]]` looks up the entry, if any exists, with the index `addr`, and returns a truthy value if that entry maps to a non-empty string.

Comment: What is the purpose of `seen=( )` instead of just `seen`?

Comment: @123, run `s=hello bash -c 'declare -A s; declare -p s'` to answer that question. (At least with bash 4.4.12(1), a possible output is `declare -Ax s=([0]="hello" )`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : It think your solution is different from what the OP asked: If an IP address different from 10.1.1.1 occurs more than once, it would also show up only once, and while this should not occur in practice in a network which is set up correctly, one would probably like to see **if** it happens.

Comment: That's a fair interpretation. I've added an amendment that allows the user to specify any number of special IPs, and tracks counts for each individually.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but maybe something like this:

```
occured_for_instance_at=
special_ip=10.1.1.1
for hosts in "${host_starting}"{1..200}."$dns"; do
    addr=`dig +short $hosts`
    if [[ $addr == $special_ip ]]
    then
      occured_for_instance_at=$hosts
    else
      echo "$addr=$hosts"
    fi
done
[[ -n "$occured_for_instance_at ]] && echo "$special_ip=$occured_for_instance_at"
```

If you don't mind getting an empty output line in the case that 10.1.1.1 doesn't show up, you could simplify it to:

```
special_ip_line=
for hosts in "${host_starting}"{1..200}."$dns"; do
    addr=`dig +short $hosts`
    if [[ $addr == 10.1.1.1 ]]
    then
      special_ip_line="$addr=$hosts"
    else
      echo "$addr=$hosts"
    fi
done
echo "$special_ip_line"
```